# Ejabberd Bosh responses with no <features> element

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to use the bosh module which is up and running on my ejabberd server.

The client (using jabbernet) starts by sending:

```
<body content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" to="localhost" wait="60" hold="1" 
 xml:lang="en-GB" rid="1368823140" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" />
```

Then I get from the server the response without a  element:

```
<body authid='17254393595248629793' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='54a265d3d69252744d63d2cf6ec74d366aa24f3b' 
 wait='60' ver='1.11' polling='2' inactivity='30' hold='1' 
 xmpp:restartlogic='true' requests='2' secure='true' maxpause='120' 
 xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' from='localhost'/>
```

Then, according to [xep-0206](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html):

> If no stream:features element is included in the connection manager's session creation response, then the client SHOULD send empty request elements until it receives a response containing a  element.

So the client sends every 2 seconds:

```
<body to="localhost" sid="54a265d3d69252744d63d2cf6ec74d366aa24f3b" rid="1368823142" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" />
```

But gets from ejabberd server only:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
```

And eventually (after 30 seconds) it fails with:

```
<body type='terminate' condition='remote-stream-error' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can see how other BOSH clients behave with ejabberd (like Gajim or Pidgin), and compare the XMPP traffic (using their "XML console", or a network sniffer like Wireshark).

Comment: Thanks, its a great idea, I will do that and update.